# category property for AppDelegate not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, appdelegate

I've extended AppDelegate with my category. The goal is initiate server request and show notification, when user entering some geofence with terminated app. This all done in class GeoNotificationManager. All I need to do - instantiate this class once app launched from location event.

Everything works, except the **PROBLEM:** - when `@property (strong) GeoNotificationManager* geof;` is inside category, code inside `GeoNotificationManager` **doesn't work** (no server requests, no notifications). And when it's inside AppDelegate itself, **everything works** as expected.

Also I tried without having property in catergory, it doesn`t work too.

```
GeoNotificationManager* manager = [GeoNotificationManager new];
[manager sendTestServerRequest:@"test"]; // REQUEST NOT SENDING, WHY???
```

```
//AppDelegate+Geofence.h

#import "AppDelegate.h"

@class GeoNotificationManager;

@interface AppDelegate (Geofence)
@property (strong) GeoNotificationManager* geof;
@end
```

```
NSString * const kNewPropertyKey = @"kNewPropertyKey";

@class GeoNotificationManager;

@implementation AppDelegate(Geofence)


-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:
(NSDictionary<UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey,id> *)launchOptions {
     if ([launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey])
     {
         self.geof = [GeoNotificationManager new];
         [self.geof sendTestServerRequest:@"test"];
         
    }
    return true;
}
 // I don't understand what is that below, but seems it's required for having property in category

- (void)setGeof:(id)aObject
{
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, (__bridge const void * _Nonnull)(kNewPropertyKey),
     aObject, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_ASSIGN);

}
- (id)geof
{
    return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, (__bridge const void * _Nonnull)(kNewPropertyKey));
}
```

```
@objc class GeoNotificationManager : NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    override init() {
        super.init()
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
        locationManager.showsBackgroundLocationIndicator = true
    }
// OTHER CODE, -didEnterRegion, server request etc
```

Comment: Not looked at your code a lot, just a comment that Objective-C categories can not contain properties.

Comment: @skaak great thanks, you push my thoughts to solution. OBJC_ASSOCIATION_ASSIGN just needed to be changed to OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN and it works

Comment: Ah thanks - glad I could help although I am not even sure how I did it he he he ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OBJC_ASSOCIATION_ASSIGN just should be replaced with OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN, and it works!
But if anyone knows how to do this with local variable, please share